# ASP.NET - Implementing javascript (Jquery?) function in code-generated table

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am creating a Table with a varying amount of rows via code only. For each such row, I want (pertaining to some condition) an image button that, once clicked, calls a method on it's particular row. The effect of which essentially being an expand/collapse function.

But I am unsure of how to do this properly. Do add a javascript as an onclientclick event that steps up through the ancestors to find the number of rows to be collapsed/expanded and then sets display: none on them?

Basic table setup:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr></tr>
                <tr></tr>
                <tr>
                    <span></span>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <span></span>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Clicking the input is supposed to toggle the visibility of the spans (or their rows) in that particular tr of the outer table.

edit: As per the user Luke's suggestion, I want to clarify that I want to be able to run this script. I.e. not have it exist as just a string somewhere in my code.

I have a class, `SpeedButtonAgenda`, that contains a Table object, which it creates upon construction. It also contains various useful fields of meta data.

This is where the Table gets created:

```
private void BuildTable()
        {
            _table = new Table() { CssClass = "speed-agenda-full-width" };

            for (int i = 0; i < _eventDates.Count(); i++)
            {
                var row = CreateRow(_eventDates.ElementAt(i));
                if (i%2 == 0)
                    row.Attributes.Add("style", "background-color: #f6f6f6");
                _table.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }
```

So, this table does get rendered on a parent page. And I have currently received great help in designing the script that connects buttons to elements that are to be toggled. But I have not figured out how to actually load the script, so to say. But just now I started thinking that maybe I should do this on the parent page (where I could do it in the .ascx).

Comment: Atleast add inputs and pseudo code? You can use jQuery [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for dynamicaaly generated elements?

Comment: I want to add as much as possible, but I just don't understand how to select through this hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help. first bind an event to input.

```
$("table input").live('click',function(){
  var rowClicked = $(this).parent();
  $(rowClicked).find("span").each(function(){
      $(this).toggle();   
   });
    // do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

using `delegation` might help see [Docs](https://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

```
$( "tr" ).delegate( "td", "click", function() {
  $( this ).toggleClass( "chosen" );
});
```

here if `td` is clicked, `tr` will notice and call the callback. `this` is a reference to `td`

```
$( "table" ).delegate( "img", "click", function() {
  $( this ).closest("tr").toggleClass( "chosen" );
});
```

here if `img` is clicked, `table` will notice and call the callback. `this` is a reference to `img`.
In the callback I´m searching for the closest `tr` element to toggle the `chosen` class only on `tr`

Comment: Does this read as the following? "For every tr element, give its td children (does it also recursively move down the hierarchy to and past grandchildren?) attach a function that toggles the css class .chosen on the td element, when td gets clicked"?

Comment: no not exactly. its more like delegate a td click of a tr to the tr

Comment: Oooh. <tr><td><img></td></td> - now if the img gets clicked, because it is in a td, the tr gets the css class .chosen?

Comment: no, sorry, there i made a mistake. here in the example, you might generate dynamically `td` elements into the `tr` element, and the callback would be triggered. if you generate dynamic `tr` the callback would *not* work. so, when you click a `td` the event bubles up to the `tr` and because it has a delegation, the callback is called with a reference (this) to the `td`

Comment: I see, thanks. I have been toying around with selectors since your previous comment also. But when I wanted to try it out, I realized: I don't know how to attach this script to my page. My original idea was to make a script that would be the onclientclick event of an input or so, but as this script attaches to the entire table, I will have to add it differently?

Comment: you are attaching the handler to the table, but it will still work for every input / image / what ever the selector would be. as in your request with my solution you can handle this almost without any further modification... if your question changed somehow, change it in the main post

Comment: Hmm... *how* am I attaching it to the table? Let's say I have a Table _table and this jquery script stored in a string. Via _table.Attributes somehow?

Comment: exactly the same way as i described in my answer. using $("table"). or if you have already a reference to it (_table) then use `$(_table)`

Comment: But how do I... register it? If that's the term. This is all in a .cs file. How do I ensure that the script gets registered when this control gets created?

Comment: this is then either another question, or you need to give more details in your main question. Right now we are using TOO MUCH comments to fix that issue. Show me how / where the table gets rendered. AND PUT IT IN THE MAIN QUESTION...

Comment: I don't really see how or why you say this wasns't covered in the original question. But I assume you are right in saying so. So I updated.